# Android Gson TypeToken NullpointerException

Tags: android, json, gson

I am trying to parse a JSONArray using Gson.
Whenever I am trying to initialize the object of class TypeToken. I see this error.

`Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.example.ResponseParser$2.toString()`

I am able to see this in debug console as I have added a debug point on this statement.

`GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
TypeToken<List<MyClass>> typeToken = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}; //debug point on this statement`

After this, the code breaks. The app does not crash but the further statements are not being executed.

Comment: @mbacvanski GSON is used on android a lot - the question is not about which JSON implementation to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
List<MyClass> items = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

There might be some issues with your class on the deserialization.